# Why does an external program freeze when launched by VS if there are breakpoints set?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I have a C# project that produces a class library. The library is consumed by an external program. The C# project is set to launch the external program on starting a debug session. The external program is a console app. The library is part of a large solution with many projects, and it references many of them. The environment is Visual Studio Premium 2013, running with Administrator privileges. Resharper Ultimate 2015.1 is installed.

Just hitting F5 works fine. The external program launches and then at the appropriate time it loads my library and runs my code. Changes to my code are immediately reflected in altered behavior on the next run. You can immediately tell that the console app is running because as soon as it starts up it starts pouring out log information to the console.

However, if I set a breakpoint somewhere in my code, and *then* hit F5, the console window appears, but remains empty, with a flashing cursor, and nothing happens. Obviously the breakpoint is never hit, and hovering over it gives the (sort of) expected "no symbols have been loaded" message.

If I clear the breakpoints (they have to be cleared, not just disabled), and then run the project, it works again, of course. And then I can quickly switch back to the IDE and set the breakpoint I wanted, and the program will continue to run, load my library, and then will hit the breakpoint just fine, at which point I can debug the code as normal.

While this is an acceptable workaround for a single breakpoint, I like to set up groups of breakpoints and enable them and disable them through the breakpoints window. This is completely unavailable to me now.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I'm pretty lost for ideas.

Comment: How does the external console app loads your class library? Can you please share the code of the library loading of the console app?

Comment: Have you tried VS2015? Also, you could try disabling VSHost, sometimes it does funky stuff. And as another workaround, you could try running without debugging, and having `Debugger.Attach` in your main method - it's an extra step compared to just pressing F5, but it's not too bad.

Comment: Couple of days ago there was a similar question and the comment was something like 'we've bee getting these questions a lot this week, uninstall Avast' - so, any chance you have Avast running?

Comment: To quickly respond to these: 

I don't have access to the code for the console app - it's from a different team in the (large) company I'm working at. We simply configure it to use our library through XML config files.

VS2015 isn't an option, it's months or more before its use will be approved across the firm.

No, don't have Avast running. That would have been a nice easy fix.

Comment: Are there any clues in the output window? It should list all the modules whose symbols are loaded.. maybe it's stuck on one of them...

Comment: What kind of breakpoints are you setting? Function breakpoints can take a long time to process when your project has a lot of large modules, especially if your symbol load settings automatically load all symbols.

Comment: Just standard breakpoints. I will try just leaving it for ages.